# Google App Engine datastore does not support operator +

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm playing with GAE, and need to make a query with something like this:

```
select from models.Post as p where (p.votesUp + p.votesDown > 10)
```

But I get this error: ***App Engine datastore does not support operator +***

Which could be a good approach to replace that query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious thing that leaps out at me is to put a method on p that has a p.netVotes and query on that.

But I'm not familiar enough with App Engine (I just started looking at it) to be sure that that works.

Comment: Thanks Yishai. That's the best solution I think :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to the issue with [counters in app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html). The simplest solution off the top of my head is to add a votesTotal attribute that is updated every time votesUp and votesDown is updated. Thus there's no large computation when you query for votesTotal > foo_val.